# Prove that if $A, B $ are convex , $B$ is closed, $C$ is bounded and $A+C \subset B+C$ then $A\subset B$

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Given the sets $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
$$A+C \subset B+C$$
Show that if $A,B$ are convex, $B$ is closed and $C$ is bounded then $A\subset B$.

I kind of understand the geometrical interpretation of the problem but I fail to see where to start, too many properties for me to handle :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry, Julio, my message was a response to somebody else who then deleted their comment without telling me.

Comment: I've attempted to solve the problem for the case where $C$ is a ball with radius $r$ and centered in the origin, making $A+C$ and $B+C$ inflated versions of $A$ and $B$. Then I tried to form a relationship between a line in $A$ and a line in $B$ but that wasn't possible, I still need to use the closure of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the following  plan will work, and not only for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but for a general case of a locally convex space $X$, satisfying the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

The convexity of $A$ is not needed, because the question condition implies $a+C\subset B+C$  for each point $a\in A$. So it suffices to consider only a case when $A$ is one-point set. Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $A={0}$. Then we should prove that $C\subset B+C$ implies $0\in B$. Suppose the opposite. Since $B$ is closed, there exist a real number $\varepsilon>0$ and a linear functional $f$ on $X$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f|B>\varepsilon$. Since $C$ is bounded, the value $c=\inf_{x\in C} f(x)<\infty$. Choose a point $x\in C$ such that $f(x)<c+\varepsilon/2$. Since $f(y+z)=f(y)+f(z)>\varepsilon+c$ for each $y\in B$ and $z\in C$, we see that $x\not\in B+C$, a contradiction.

Comment: What guarantees the existence of the linear functional $f$. The only tools that I was given in class to demonstrate this were Caratheodorys Theorem, definition and some properties of closed set, convex hull, bound sets and convex sets. (I feel my teacher is cheating)

Comment: Such a linear functional exists by [Hahn-Banach separation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem). Geometrically it should mean that there is a hyperplane strictly separating the zero from the set $B$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand the answer, the problem is that I haven't taken a course of functional analysis yet and I don't think the teacher would allow me to use the Hanh-Banach theorem. :/

Comment: @JulioCáceres I think in this case the teacher would be bad. :-)

Comment: Of course, there is an idea of the solution based on the spatial intuition and without an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem. We need to find a hyperplane $L$ strictly separating the set $B$ from the zero. Then the canonical hyperplane equation for $L$ should give to us the needed linear functional. Let $b$ be a  point in $B$, which is closest to the zero. Such a point should exist, because $B$ is closed and should be unique, since $B$ is convex. As $L$ we may take a hyperplane passing through the midpoint of the segment $[0,b]$ and orthogonal to this segment.

Comment: Yea, as soon as you mentioned hyperplane I realized that was the key, thanks a lot