# Sum of sets in a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-hulls

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the following properties:
$A$ is not empty and bounded and $C$ is closed and convex.
Show that:

a) If $A+B\subseteq A+C$, then $B\subseteq C$.

b) If $B$ is closed and convex with $A+B=A+C$ then, $B=C$.

Any hint or solutions, or maybe a textbook with a reference or theory usefull in this problem. Thanks in advanace.

For part $b)$ we also assume that $B$ is convex.

Comment: How is your addition defined?

Comment: elementwise $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A b\in B\}$

Comment: @RobertThingum any help?

Comment: The question seems to be about sets in $\mathbb R^n$ so why "topological space" in the title?

Comment: @bof.  Because C is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361725/prove-that-if-a-b-are-convex-b-is-closed-c-is-bounded-and-ac-subse).
Part b is false. For instance, put $n=1$, $A=C=[0,1]$, $B=\{0,1\}$.